# importing mysql dumping file to vagrant with salt

Tags: mysql, vagrant, salt

I am using vagrant with salt to setup a dev environment but I can't find the way to import the mysql script with in the salt configuration

Answer (score 0):

I've re-used an example from [this script](https://github.com/moreda/zabbix-formula/blob/master/zabbix/mysql/schema.sls) to solve it. Once the SQL is applied, a marker file is created with `touch` that is later checked with `test`:

```
{% for file in [
  '/usr/share/zabbix-server-mysql/salt-provided-schema.sql',
  '/usr/share/zabbix-server-mysql/salt-provided-images.sql',
  '/usr/share/zabbix-server-mysql/salt-provided-data.sql'
] %}
{{ file }}:
  file:
    - managed
    - makedirs: True
    - source: {{ files_switch('zabbix', [ file ]) }}
  cmd:
    - run
    - name: /usr/bin/mysql -h {{ dbhost }} -u {{ dbuser }} --password={{ dbpass }} {{ dbname }} < {{ file }} && touch {{ file }}.applied
    - unless: test -f {{ file }}.applied
    - require:
      - file: {{ file }}
      - pkg: mysql-client
{% endfor %}
```